Use R to create polygons of cities from city names with OSMdata
When creating polygons with the code underneath it grabs a lot of states and non-cities, I only want cities. I need to filter for only using cities in R using OSMdata or another spatial dataset
library(osmdata)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

# Function to convert bounding box to polygon with error handling
bbox_to_polygon <- function(location, country) {
  # Attempt to get bounding box from osmdata
  bbox <- tryCatch(
    {
      # Append the country information after the location
      location_full <- paste(location, country, sep = ", ")
      # Special handling for Brasilia
      location_full <- if_else(location == "brasilia", paste(location, "city", sep = ", "), location_full)
      getbb(location_full)
    },
    error = function(e) {
      message(paste("Error retrieving bounding box for:", location_full, ":", e$message))
      return(NULL)
    }
  )
  
  # If bbox is NULL, return NULL
  if (is.null(bbox)) {
    return(NULL)
  }
  
  # Extract min and max coordinates
  min_x <- bbox["x", "min"]
  max_x <- bbox["x", "max"]
  min_y <- bbox["y", "min"]
  max_y <- bbox["y", "max"]
  
  # Create a matrix of the coordinates for the polygon
  coords <- matrix(c(
    min_x, min_y,
    max_x, min_y,
    max_x, max_y,
    min_x, max_y,
    min_x, min_y
  ), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
  
  # Create the polygon
  polygon <- st_polygon(list(coords))
  
  # Create an sf object
  sf_polygon <- st_sfc(polygon, crs = 4326)
  
  return(sf_polygon)
}

# Function to create a polygon from a row
polygon_from_row <- function(row) {
  loc <- row$name
  country <- row$country.etc
  bbox_to_polygon(loc, country)
}

Tried different functions and search methods

Welcome to Stackoverflow. If you are looking for Brazil specific municipal polys, ibge planning were updated 2022 for current hydrological patterns with polygons available for download. IBGE is the national statistics and planning dept. from the above could only guess.

There are alternatives to using OSM, but in order to offer a tailored solution, you will need to update your question with a vector of city names and country (Brazil?). Alternatively, if you don't have a vector of names, you could add the coordinate extent (bbox values) or feature extent e.g. name of state.

I want to use it for multiple countries, like France, Germany and South Africa
